# How to correctly interpolate multi-dimension data?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, python-xarray

I have a 6d DataArray named `data` and want to use six 2d variables to interpolate the data.
The example netcdf file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WQLr77oarH40zY_lVOjIj6K1C6BqUDqQ/view?usp=sharing).

```
Data variables:
    interp_var1  (y, x) float32 nan nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan nan
    interp_var2  (y, x) float32 nan nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan nan
    interp_var3  (y, x) float32 nan nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan nan
    interp_var4  (y, x) float32 nan nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan nan
    interp_lon   (y, x) float32 122.9 122.9 123.0 123.1 ... 95.07 94.95 94.82
    interp_lat   (y, x) float32 82.24 82.27 82.3 82.33 ... 86.48 86.53 86.58
    data         (var1, var2, var3, var4, lon, lat) float64 ...
```

### Interp()

First, I tried the `interp()` function:

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


ds_test = xr.open_dataset('test_multi_interp.nc')


interp_dict = {'var1': ds_test['interp_var1'],
                'var2': ds_test['interp_var2'],
                'var3': ds_test['interp_var3'],
                'var4': ds_test['interp_var4'],
                'lon': ds_test['interp_lon'],
                'lat': ds_test['interp_lat'],
                }

ds_test['data'].interp(interp_dict).plot(vmin=0)
```

[image: example]

There're many missing data as shown on the left panel.
So, I tried to use extrapolation.

### Interp with extrapolation

```
ds_test['data'].interp(interp_dict, kwargs={"fill_value": None}).plot(vmin=0)
```

[image: example2]

Many missing data are filled, but the large white strips are still there.

### Cause

So, I tried to find out the cause of the white stripes by neglecting one dimension of interpolation at each time.

When I drop any `var` (var1~var4) or `lon` from the `interp_dict`, the white stripes always exist:

```
novar4_dict = {i:interp_dict[i] for i in interp_dict if i!='var4'}

ds_test['data'].interp(novar4_dict, kwargs={"fill_value": None}).isel(var4=slice(0,6)).plot(col='var4', col_wrap=3, vmin=0)
```

[image: example3]

Finally, the root is the `lat` dimension:

```
nolat_dict = {i:interp_dict[i] for i in interp_dict if i!='lat'}

ds_test['data'].interp(nolat_dict, kwargs={"fill_value": None}).isel(lat=slice(16,22)).plot(col='lat', col_wrap=3, vmin=0)
```

[image: example4]

Let's take the first white stripe as an example.
The `lat` is from 83 to 84 in that region (as shown below) and the extrapolation should work well because there're valid data values between 81.5 and 83.5 (as shown above).

[image: example5]

How to use the interpolation to fill the stripes correctly?

### Attempt 1

I tried to apply `interp()` on `lat` dimension after the multi-dimension interpolation:

```
ds_test['data'].interp(nolat_dict, kwargs={"fill_value": None}).interp(lat=ds_test['interp_lat'])
```

But, it failed:

```
File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/core/utils.py:459, in Frozen.__getitem__(self, key)
    458 def __getitem__(self, key: K) -> V:
--> 459     return self.mapping[key]

KeyError: 'y'
```

### Attempt 2

Iterating the interpolation result without lat and applying `interp1d` manually gives similar results.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

da_interp = ds_test['data'].interp(nolat_dict, kwargs={"fill_value": None})

result = np.empty(da_interp.shape[:-1])

for i in range(da_interp.sizes['y']):
    for j in range(da_interp.sizes['x']):
        f = interp1d(da_interp.lat, da_interp.isel(y=i, x=j), axis=-1, kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')
        result[i, j] = f(ds_test['interp_lat'].sel(y=i, x=j))

xr.DataArray(result).rename({'dim_0': 'y', 'dim_1': 'x'}).plot(vmin=0)
```

[image: example6]

Let's pick one grid to investigate why it fails:

```
da_interp.isel(y=30, x=40).plot(marker='o')
plt.axvline(ds_test['interp_lat'].isel(y=30, x=40), c='red', label='interp_lat at y=30,x=40')
plt.legend()
plt.title('da_interp at y=30,x=40')

i = 30; j = 40
f = interp1d(da_interp.lat, da_interp.isel(y=i, x=j), axis=-1, kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')

print(da_interp.isel(y=i, x=j))
print(f(ds_test['interp_lat'].sel(y=i, x=j)))
```

[image: example7]

Although there're three valid values before the interp_lat, `interp_1d` returns `nan`.

```
<xarray.DataArray 'data' (lat: 25)>
array([            nan,             nan,             nan,             nan,
                   nan,             nan,             nan,             nan,
                   nan,             nan,             nan,             nan,
                   nan, -2.35975262e-06,             nan,             nan,
        6.67684124e-06,  6.35597345e-06,  3.44029654e-06,             nan,
                   nan,             nan,             nan,             nan,
                   nan])
```

Even if I interpolate data along `lat` dim and then apply `interp1d`:

```
i = 30; j = 40

f = interp1d(da_interp.lat, da_interp.isel(y=i, x=j).interpolate_na(dim='lat'), axis=-1, kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')

print(f(ds_test['interp_lat'].sel(y=i, x=j)))

print(da_interp.isel(y=i, x=j).interpolate_na(dim='lat'))
```

It's still nan:

```
nan
<xarray.DataArray 'data' (lat: 25)>
array([            nan,             nan,             nan,             nan,
                   nan,             nan,             nan,             nan,
                   nan,             nan,             nan,             nan,
                   nan, -2.35975262e-06,  6.52445336e-07,  3.66464329e-06,
        6.67684124e-06,  6.35597345e-06,  3.44029654e-06,             nan,
                   nan,             nan,             nan,             nan,
                   nan])
```

Comment: I added another question based on `Attempt 2`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70904549/7347925. Hope that can help you answer this advanced question.