# interp1d gives nan with extrapolation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate data that has nan values using `interp1d` with extrapolation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(11)
y = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 9, 7, 6, np.nan, np.nan])

f = interp1d(x, y, axis=-1, kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')
print(f(8.8))

plt.scatter(x, y, label='data')
plt.axvline(8.8, c='red', label='interpolation position')
plt.legend()
```

But, the result is NaN.

[image: example]

Even if I pick a subset of `x`, it is still nan:

```
f = interp1d(x[6:], y[6:], axis=-1, kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')
print(f(8.8))

plt.scatter(x[6:], y[6:], label='data')
plt.axvline(8.8, c='red', label='interpolation position')
plt.legend()
```

[image: example2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `nan`s before interpolating:

```
valid = np.nonzero(~np.isnan(y))
f = interp1d(x[valid], y[valid], axis=-1, kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')

print(f(8.8))
# 5.199999999999999
```